# Symfony 4 redirect after user authentication on IIS (sf_redirect cookie)

Tags: php, symfony, iis, cookies, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4 and need users to be authenticated before accessing any page. These are my firewall-settings:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout        # logout-route
            target: app_loggedout   # where to go after successful logout
```

And this is the access_control (also in security.yaml):

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/loggedout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

The class UserAuthenticator is called, users are authenticated automatically (because of the username that is provided in the $_SERVER-variable).

But now: I want the user to be redirected to the original URL after the authentication. E.g. if the user wants to go to SITE/test, this should happen automatically after they pass through the UserAuthenticator.
I have managed to achieve this by using the sf_redirect-cookie which Symfony seems to set automatically, it contains something like this:

```
{"token":"b2282c","route":"app_some_url","method":"GET","controller":{"class":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController","method":"some_method","file":"<PATH>\\src\\Controller\\SecurityController.php","line":23},"status_code":302,"status_text":"Found"}
```

In my UserAuthenticator I check if the cookie is there, is filled and has a route set and then return a RedirectRespone leading to the route in onAuthenticationSuccess().

The problem is: While this works fine on Apache (dev-system), the sf_redirect-cookie is missing completely on IIS (prod-system). It's not that IIS would not set cookies at all (`$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` is there), it's just that sf_redirect is missing.

I've been experimenting with a custom subscriber to the redirect-to-login-event, but I'd rather not use a workaround, so the question is: How can I tell Symfony to set the sf_redirect-cookie on IIS, or how do I need to configure IIS to set it?

Comment: Did you use https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Util/TargetPathTrait.php in your Authenticator? If not could you add your Authenticator to your question please

Comment: Thanks for getting back. No, I wasn't using TargetPathTrait, I didn't even know it existed, the example for a custom UserAuthenticator in the Symfony documentation didn't include this bit. I just added it as `return new RedirectResponse($this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), 'main'));` and it works like a charm. Feel free to leave your comment as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [TargetPathTrait](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Util/TargetPathTrait.php) to your authenticator to redirect the user after successful login.

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    ....

    return new RedirectResponse($this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey));

    ....
}
```